# Terminology question in linear algebra - a set that is closed under multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

Let $X$ be a (real) vector space.
Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $X$.
If $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication,
then we call $S$ a subspace.
If $S$ is closed under multiplication by nonnegative scalars,
then we call $S$ a cone (that may or may not be convex).

My question is:

> What do we call $S$ if $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication?

Note: $S$ need not be closed under addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Bourbaki (EVT I.1.5 Definition 3, II.2.4 Definition 3), such a thing may be called a *balanced cone.*

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much!